# Consumir uma API que exige autenticação com Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, node.js, api

Estou criando uma aplicação com Laravel, no qual consiste consumir a API da McAfee.

A versão anterior foi construída em php puro, da qual consumia os dados de um banco Mysql alimentado por um script NodeJs que consumia a API.

A questão é, a API exige autenticação para consumir os dados, o qual era feito com o método Auth do axios conforme abaixo:

```
import axios from 'axios';
import https from 'https';
import sequelize from 'sequelize';

class requisitionController {
    async store(req, res) {
        try {
            const agent = new https.Agent({  
            rejectUnauthorized: false
            });
            const response = await axios.get('https://ePODirectory:port/remote/core.executeQuery?target=EPOLeafNode&select=(select%20EPOComputerProperties.ComputerName%20EPOComputerProperties.IPAddress%20EPOLeafNode.LastUpdate%20EPOComputerProperties.OSType%20EPOLeafNode.ManagedState%20EPOProdPropsView_EPOAGENT.productversion%20EPOProdPropsView_VIRUSCAN.datver)%22&:output=json', {
            httpsAgent: agent,
            auth: {
                username: '*********',
                password: '*********'
            }
            });

            const responseJSON  = JSON.parse(response.data.replace('OK:', ''));

            return res.json(responseJSON);
        } catch(err) {
            return res.json(err);
        }
    }
}

export default new requisitionController();
```

Minha pergunta é, é possível consumir essa API com PHP/Laravel realizando essa autenticação?

Agradeço desde já :-)

Comment: É possível sim, você vai utilizar o `guzzlehttp/guzzle` para fazer a comunicação com a API de destino e na chamada da rota você vai passar os parâmetros de autenticação que a API precisa.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sim é possível, você deverá fazer algo mais ou menos assim:

Instalar a biblioteca do guzzle para conseguir consumir a API.

```
composer require guzzlehttp/guzzle
```

Depois você vai consumir a rota desejada.

```
$url = 'https://ePODirectory:port/remote/core.executeQuery?target=EPOLeafNode&select=(select%20EPOComputerProperties.ComputerName%20EPOComputerProperties.IPAddress%20EPOLeafNode.LastUpdate%20EPOComputerProperties.OSType%20EPOLeafNode.ManagedState%20EPOProdPropsView_EPOAGENT.productversion%20EPOProdPropsView_VIRUSCAN.datver)%22&:output=json';
$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();
$client->request(
    'GET',
    $url,
    [
        'auth' = [
            'username',
            'password' 
        ]
    ]
);
```

Comment: Implementei o código acima, mas toda vez que executo tenho o seguinte erro: Undefined offset:0. Para exibir o resultado fiz o seguinte: $response -> recebe o $client request, então dou um echo $response->getBody(); Testei a requisição pelo Postman, e correu tudo certo.

Comment: Tente pegar o resultado assim: `$response->getBody()->getContents();`

Comment: Dei uma lida na documentação, o Guzzle espera o username no index(0) e a senha no index(1) do método Auth. Apenas removi os campos "username" e ''password'', deixando apenas os valores dos mesmo. Funcionou, mas agora estou com um erro de SSL certificate, mas acredito ter a ver com a rede interna que utilizo. No mais, resolveu meu problema :-)

Answer (score 0):

Apenas complementando e trazendo a sintaxe da versão 8 do Laravel:

1. Instale o Guzzle:

   composer require guzzlehttp/guzzle
2. No código você importa e faz uma requisição (GET, POST...)

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Http;

$response = Http::withToken('token')->post(http://example.com);
```

3. Métodos de uma instância de Response:

```
$response->body() : string;
$response->json() : array|mixed;
$response->object() : object;
$response->collect() : Illuminate\Support\Collection;
$response->status() : int;
$response->ok() : bool;
$response->successful() : bool;
$response->failed() : bool;
$response->serverError() : bool;
$response->clientError() : bool;
$response->header($header) : string;
$response->headers() : array;
```

Fonte: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/http-client

Answer (score -2):

Claro que sim,desde que você passe as chaves de autenticação durante a requisição para a API,a vantagem de usar API de Web Services é que você pode mesclar várias tecnologias diferentes.